Calculate resistance in circuit with different coloured LEDs
First time caller... I've not done electronics since school - which was err... all theory, nothing practical... like Light Emitting Diodes. So go easy on me, I bruise like a peach.
I plan to add three 3mm LEDs to light up a plastic model kit - hopefully powered by a 5v USB cable. It's a simple circuit, originally in done series, but when adding the resistors using ledcalculator I noticed it got changed to parallel. - So let's stick with that.

Since ledcalculator assumes the colours to be the same, and I'm after one blue and two orange. The voltage drop is different for these coloured LEDs. So my question is in two parts:
How do I calculate the resistance with different coloured LEDs in parallel so I know what to purchase? Secondly, if the coloured LEDs change places either by error or design, how does that alter things?

The way the switch is placed, it short-circuits the battery when closed, which is generally a very bad idea. Place it "before" or "after" the LEDs (i.e. next to the battery).

Since the LEDs are in parallel they do not affect one another and the resistors choices will be the same (for each color) no matter how many colors are present.  Therefore you can use your calculator multiple times, one per color and then use that resistor for each instance of that color.  And yes, fix your switch to cut the power rather than short it to ground.

You wish to match brightness of different colour LEDs. Apparent light output varies a lot with colour, and also with the material of which LEDs are made. It may be easier to collect a bunch of resistor values (higher values yield less brightness).

Pretty straightforward - Ohm's Law + datasheets.
Start with the forward voltage (Vf) for each LED.  This is the voltage drop across the LED when it is conducting current and emitting light.  The datasheet will have a typical value for many of the specs, usually 20 mA.  Selecting the operating current is a design decision.  The calculations flow down from this.  The currents can be different for each LED.
The power source is a constant for all diodes, and Vf is a constant for each diode.  Subtract Vf from Vcc and you get the voltage across each resistor.  You already know the current, so Ohm's Law gives you the resistance for that loop.
Example:
Orange LED Vf = 2.1 V
Vcc = 5.0 V
LED current = 20 mA
R = E / I
Rorange = (5.0 - 2.1) / .02 = 145 ohms.  The closest 5% value is 150 ohms.
Rather than identifiers such as Rorange, better to assign a unique reference designator to each component.  R1, R2, D3, D17, etc.
The Vf difference between orange and blue is significant.  Without getting into the efficacies of the different LEDs (the amount of light per mA of current), changing the LED places - that is, moving the LED placements in the circuit without moving their resistors - will change their relative brightnesses.
Once you have a set of initial resistor values, swap the positions of one orange LED and the blue one.  Now the voltages are known and the resistors are known, so you can calculate the currents through the resistors and see how they changed.
If the three diodes are D1 - D3 and the three resistors are R1 - R3, and you swap D1 and D2, then ...
I = E / R
I(D1) = (Vcc - Vf(D1)) / R2
and
I(D2) = (Vcc - Vf(D2)) / R1

Thanks for the check mark.  Any follow-up questions?

I've taken note of the useful comments above and make changes. A question now, looking at LED specs, is do I calculate for MAX forward voltage or TYPICAL forward voltage??

Depends on the application.  For any fixed resistor value, as Vf decreases, the current through the loop (resistor and LED) increases.  If you pick a resistor value based on the max Vf, then the majority of LEDs of that part number from that manufacturer will be operating at a current above the typical value in the datasheet.  For a typical home project, I would design around the typical Vf and typical current.

To expand:  For a design based on a fixed voltage and fixed resistor value, you design around max Vf if you are concerned with the brightness not going below a certain minimum value.  You design around min Vf if you are concerned about the LED current not going above a certain maximum value.
